# c++ static function unfound

Tags: c++, static, function

I have this definition of the function in my class.

The `.hpp` file:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:

static string DoStuff(string s);

};
```

The `.cpp` file:

```
#include "header.hpp"

string SomeClass::DoStuff(string s)
{
// do something
}
```

Compiler says:

```
**error C2039: 'DoStuff' : is not a member of 'SomeClass'**
```

Can somebody help?

EDIT:
actual offending code

header definition

```
  class DDateTime{  
public:
static string date2OracleDate(DATE Date);
}


string DDateTime::date2OracleDate(DATE Date)
{
    string s;
    s="TO_DATE('" + DDateTime::DateFormat("%d/%m/%Y",Date) + "','dd/MM/YYYY')";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: have you tried compiling that exact example, or did you simplify it for us?  that looks like it should work...

Comment: Could you possibly be using two different definitions of `string`?  Does one of the sites specify `const` (on either the parameter or method)?

Comment: You miss a `;` at the end of your class declaration.

Comment: @Tony:  Even your 'actual offending code' compiles just fine.  Your problem is elsewhere and you are not offering up enough context for anyone to spot the problem.

Comment: Agreed, not enough information. Aside from the semicolon missing, what's string supposed to be? std::string? If so, the header should specify the namespace and I hope you don't have using declarations/directives in any of your headers as that's a definite no-no.

Comment: I fixed it!!! There was two header files for the same CPP file, and one had missing function definitions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `.cpp` files must include the matching `.h` or `.hpp` file.

Is it the case here ?

You can also have namespace issue (missing namespace in `.cpp` file or static method definition outside of the namespace, and so on.).

Actually, it is difficult to answer until we have the real breaking code.

---

Moreover, I don't know if this is sample code, but it seems you used something like `using std::string` or `using namespace std` in your header file.

This is a bad idea because it will polute every file in which your header is included. What If someone wants to use your header file but don't want to "use" `std` because `string` is the name of one of its classes ?

Comment: Header is included in cpp.  It finds the other defined functions... also static functions...

Comment: @Tony: Please post the actual breaking code as it is obvious that what you posted is not the code that actually poses you a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the header file in your cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a namespace issue? You could have a SomeNamespace::SomeClass with a static member function and a ::SomeClass in the outer namespace without the static member function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing

```
#include<string>
```

in your header file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call DoStuff from a double pointer to your instance? Example:

SomeClass **class;
class->DoStuff();

If so do this:

SomeClass **class;
(*class)->DoStuf();